# Silent push noitification in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows, push-notification, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Can we send silent push notification in windows phone 8.1 from web service? Notification should be shown in action center without any alerts.

Comment: see this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868245.aspx#pncodes_x_wns_suppresspopup

Comment: Thanks. Really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set WNS 'X-WNS-SuppressPopup' value either True or False for achieving this.

> X-WNS-SuppressPopup: true | false Value
>   Description
>
> true   Send the
>   toast notification directly to the action center; do not raise the
>   toast UI.
>
> false  Default. Raise the toast UI as well as adding the
>   notification to the action center.

Please read msdn link for more details .
[Wns Suppress popup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868245.aspx#pncodes_x_wns_suppresspopup)